# find() vs binary_search() in STL

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

Which function is more efficient in searching an element in vector **find()** or **binary_search()** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is: `std::find` for unsorted data and `std::binary_search` for sorted data. But I think there's much more to this:

Both methods take a range `[start, end)` with `n` elements and and a value `x` that is to be found as input. But note the important difference that `std::binary_search` *only returns a `bool`* that tells you wether the range contained the element, or not. `std::find()` returns an iterator. So both have different, but overlapping use cases.

---

[`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is pretty straight forward. `O(n)` iterator increments and `O(n)` comparisons. Also it doesn't matter wether the input data is sorted or not.

---

For [`std::binary_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) you need to consider multiple factors:

- It only works on sorted data. You need to take the cost of sorting into account.
- The number of comparisons is always `O(log n)`.
- If the iterator does not satisfy [`LegacyRandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) the number of iterator increments is `O(n)`, it will be logarithmic when they do satisfy this requirement.

---

Conclusion (a bit opinionated):

- when you operate on un-sorted data or need the location of the item you searched for you *must* use `std::find()`
- when your data is already sorted or needs to be sorted anyway and you simply want to check if an element is present or not, use `std::binary_search()`
- If you want to search containers like `std::set`, `std::map` or their unordered counterparts also consider their builtin methods like [`std::set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find)

Comment: As an additional note: `binary_search` is faster for large ranges but not necessarily for small ranges.

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure if the data is sorted or not, You have to use `find()` and If the data will be sorted you should use `binary_search()`.

For more information, You can refer [find()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) and [binary_search()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/)

Answer (score 0):

If your input is sorted then you can use binary_search as it will take O(lg n) time. if your input is unsorted you can use find, which will take O(n) time.